# Xamarin DataTemplate timed refresh of viewModel, iOS refreshes the entire page, how to just update progress bar like Android does?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Unknown list of students (1-99?) Each student card has a progress bar (if applicable). Update on a timed interval. (# of students can change depending on data, time of day, etc, but doesn't update as much as progress bar)

Everything works fine on android, on interval the viewModel is updated and if theres a change, progress bar changes... on iOS it refreshes the entire page (Which is annoying if you've scrolled down to check on a specific student and have to keep doing that)

Is it possible to get the same outcome on iOS?

Heres a snippit of the TodayPage.xaml

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="runTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid> ....
    <DataTemplate x:Key="studentTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid> ...
                  <ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" x:Name="pb_TodayRun" Margin="0,0" Progress="{Binding progress}" ProgressColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" IsVisible="{Binding displayPB}"></ProgressBar>

    <toolkit:TodayDataTemplateSelector x:Key="todayDataTemplateSelector"
        RunTemplate="{StaticResource runTemplate}"
        StudentTemplate="{StaticResource studentTemplate}"
        TopTemplate="{StaticResource topTemplate}" />
```

Some of the code behind:

```
 public partial class TodayPage : ContentPage
    {
        TodayViewModel viewModel;
        private bool isShown = true;

        public TodayPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = viewModel = AppContainer.Resolve<TodayViewModel>();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            UpdateProgress(true);
            isShown = true;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60/*viewModel.AutoRefreshTime*/), () =>
            {
                if (isShown)
                {
                    UpdateProgress(false);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            });
        }
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            isShown = false;
        }

        public async void UpdateProgress(bool allowCached)
        {
            await viewModel.LoadItems(allowCached);
        }
```

and TodayViewModel.cs

```
 public class TodayViewModel : BaseViewModel , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly IStudentService _studentService;
        private readonly ISettingsService _settingsService;

        public ObservableCollection<TodayCell> Items { get; set; }

        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }
        public int AutoRefreshTime
        {
            get => _settingsService.AutoRefreshTimeSetting;
        }

        public TodayViewModel(IConnectionService connectionService, IDialogService dialogService, IStudentService studentService, ISettingsService settingsService)
            : base(connectionService, dialogService)
        {
            _studentService = studentService;
            _settingsService = settingsService;
            Items = new ObservableCollection<TodayCell>
            {
                new TodayCell.Top()
            };
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async (Object param) => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand(param != null && param.Equals(true)));
        }

        public async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand(bool allowCached)
        {
            if (IsBusy) return;
            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                await LoadItems(allowCached);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the critical code - LoadItems method, but from the style it is easy to guess that it assigns values to Items and that results in unwanted behavior.

If you expect new items to come or go you should use Add and Remove method.

As this is likely not the case, you should implement PropertyChanged on your item class and indicate that something has changed there on each item when you refresh the list.

Comment: Thanks, items was being reset. I was calling load items and re assigning, but if iOS can tell its not the exact same object, i'll need to rewrite this and find/update instead.